# User input first and last name , print out intisials java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, string, user-input

So , im having a piece of trouble here , tried with tutorials to fix it but nothing really helped me out saw something about printout string 0,1 etc but didnt work eather.

What the program does atm : Asks user for first/last name and prints it out first +last name

what i want it to do is print out the intisials of the users first and last name, any ideas how to fix this? Please help , Thanks in advance!

My code looks like this atm

```
package com.example.sträng.main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String firstName,
         lastName;

        //Create scanner to obtain user input
         Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner( System.in );

        //obtain user input
         System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
         firstName = scanner1.nextLine();

         System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
         lastName = scanner1.nextLine();

        //output information
         System.out.print("Your first name is " + firstName + " and your last name is "+ lastName);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You get the 21st character from a `String` using [`String.charAt(21)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29). 
How to get the initials, I leave as an excercise for you.

Please note, that `char` is a strange datatype in Java. It represents a character, but works like a number, that's why you get a strange number if you "concatenate" two chars. If you want to create a String out of `char`s, you have some options, such as:

```
char c1;
char c2;
String str = "" + c1 + c2;
```

or

```
char c1;
char c2;
String str = new String(new char[] {c1, c2});
```

Comment: thanks mate ill try to figure it out ill get back to you on how it worked out !

Comment: System.out.print(firstName.charAt(0));
System.out.print(lastName.charAt(0));´ got it ! just one question if u can answere , when i try to put both in same line like system.out.print(lastName.charAT(0) + firstName.charAt(0)); i get a strange value like 201 any idea why?

Comment: charAt returns type char, you'll have to use Character.toString(char)

Answer (score 0):

```
String firstInitial = firstName.substring(0,1);
String secondInitial = lastName.substring(0,1);
```

Comment: could anyone explain the substring(0,1)? please

Comment: Sure, this will return a string from a string, the parameters are (int beginIndex, int endIndex). So for example with a string of "abc123" if we called substring(1 ,3) it would return "bc1"